# Errors when installing MySQL-python package after mysql-connector-c got upgraded

Tags: python, mysql, pip, mysql-python

Previously, my installation works normally, since it uses pip's cache directory. But when I installed a brew package, brew automatically removed mysql-connector-c, and added mysql-client 8.0.19 instead. From that moment, my application can't connect to the DB anymore:

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module: dlopen([venv_location]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so, 2): 
Library not loaded: /usr/local/opt/mysql-connector-c/lib/libmysqlclient.18.dylib   
Referenced from: [venv_location]/lib/python2.7/site-packages/_mysql.so Reason: image not found.
```

It seems that the MySQL-python package still points to the old mysql-connector-c. I decided to reinstall the package without using the cache:

```
pip install MySQL-python==1.2.5 --no-cache-dir
```

But I got this error instead:

```
creating build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7
cc -fno-strict-aliasing -fno-common -dynamic -g -Os -pipe -fno-common -fno-strict-aliasing -fwrapv -DENABLE_DTRACE -DMACOSX -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wshorten-64-to-32 -iwithsysroot /usr/local/libressl/include -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Os -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -DENABLE_DTRACE -I/usr/local/opt/openssl/include -arch x86_64 -pipe -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 -I/usr/local/opt/mysql-client/include/mysql -I/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7 -c _mysql.c -o build/temp.macosx-10.15-x86_64-2.7/_mysql.o
_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found
#include "my_config.h"
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
error: command 'cc' failed with exit status 1
```

I have searched for this error, but the answers are usually related to **brew install mysql-connector-c**, while this package is not available from brew anymore. So how can I handle this exception?

Here is my /usr/local/opt (../Cellar/mysql-client/6.1.11 is invalid since it has been upgraded):

```
mysql-client -> ../Cellar/mysql-client/8.0.19
mysql-connector-c -> ../Cellar/mysql-client/6.1.11
```

Should I reinstall the old version of mysql-client to install MySQL-python from cache and keep using the old version? Or is there another way to deal with **'my_config.h' file not found**?

Answer (score 1):

This procedure worked for me (I'm adding the mysql-client and the mysql-connector-c removal to it):

```
brew remove mysql mysql-client mysql-connector-c
brew install mysql@5.7
brew link --force mysql@5.7
pip install mysql-python
```

I read a post and adjusted the procedure to link things in the /usr/local/bin instead of adding a new route to the PATH variable.
Reference: [MacOS: "pip install MySQL-python" returning an error: "_mysql.c:44:10: fatal error: 'my_config.h' file not found"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63990900/macos-pip-install-mysql-python-returning-an-error-mysql-c4410-fatal-err)